# Algebraically closed subfields of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

What are the algebraically closed subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ ?

There is $\mathbb{C}$, there is $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$... but what else ?

Comment: More generally, take the algebraic closure of any countable subfield $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots)$. The result will be countable, so not equal to $\mathbf{C}$. There are many other similar constructions.

Comment: Thank you, I've not thought of that !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $\Bbb C$ has uncountable transcendance degree over $\Bbb Q$, there is plenty of room between $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ and $\Bbb C$. Just adjoin any countable collection of algebraically independent complex numbers to $\Bbb Q$ and take the algebraic closure. And some uncountable collections will fail to generate all of $\Bbb C$ as well. There are really too much of these for any serious attempt to classify them.