# Examples of elementary substructures of $(\mathbb{C},0,1,+,-, \times)$

Tags: logic, model-theory

I wonder what are some examples of elementary substructures of $(\mathbb{C},0,1,+,-, \times)$. I know that $(\mathbb{R},0,1,+,-, \times)$, $(\mathbb{Q},0,1,+,-, \times)$ are not since they don't satisfy $x^2=-1$.

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The theory of $(\mathbb{C}, 0, 1, +, -, \cdot)$ is precisely the theory of characteristic 0 algebraically complete fields, since the latter is complete...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commenters have mentioned, any elementary substructure of $\mathbb{C}$ must satisfy the same first order properties. But it is well known that $\mathsf{ACF}_0$ (the theory of Algebraically Closed Fields of characteristic $0$) is [model complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_complete_theory). This follows, for instance, from quantifier elimination.

How is this helpful?

Any elementary substructure of $\mathbb{C}$ must, in particular, model $\mathsf{ACF}_0$, since it is clear that $\text{Th}(\mathbb{C}) \supseteq \mathsf{ACF}_0$. But by model completeness, we get the converse: any submodel $\mathfrak{M}$ of $\mathbb{C}$ that models $\mathsf{ACF}_0$ must be elementary!

So we're looking for the subrings of $\mathbb{C}$ which are themselves algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$.

We see one obvious elementary substructure: $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. However, there are lots more! For a more detailed discussion about the algebraically closed subfields of $\mathbb{C}$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369174/algebraically-closed-subfields-of-mathbbc) for instance.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Nice answer. But I wouldn't call the issue of formulas with parameters a "minor detail". In general, a structure may have elementarily equivalent substructures which are not elementary substructures! The fact that this does not happen for models of ACF$_0$ is the statement that ACF$_0$ is model complete, which follows from elimination of quantifiers.

Comment: @NoahSchweber you beat me by 10 seconds!

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yours was more accurate though :P

Comment: I agree - I was actually in the middle of changing that when you both commented :P